# How to call Rails ActiveModel.some_class_method from external thread without of connections broking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, activerecord, activemodel

I have a Rails (4.2.6) app and my extending class 'lib/messaging.rb':

```
# lib/messaging.rb
class Messaging

  include Singleton

  # this method could be called from continous thread from antoher class from 'lib'
  def event_starts_today
    Thread.new{ Friend.invite }
  end

  def invitation_accepted(friends)
    Thread.new do
      # using this to obtain and close connection within the new thread
      friends.each do |friend|
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
          Friend.find(friend.id).thanks}
        end
      end
  end

end
```

which communicates with the class Friend:

```
# app/models/friend.rb
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.invite
    free_friends = []
    # trying to protect this for calls from external threads
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      free_friend = Friend.where(is_busy: false).to_a
    end
    Messaging.instance.invitation_accepted free_friends
  end

  def say_thanks
    ...
  end
end
```

I suggest that I am doing not in the best way, but Your help would help to understand the way))

The problem outstands in exceptions's messages:

- No connection pool
- ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

I followed pt.3 from recommendations here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html#method-i-checkout
and other publications that leaded me to understanding that if I use a query on an ActiveModel within a separate Thread then I have to close the connection within this thread.

These lead me to using ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection(&block) method.

And there is still something wrong(

I suggest that I need to join Messaging and Friends somehow in Rails way, but I am confused if the only way is to make http requests(and then all the process will be under Rails controlled threads). I can't catch how to move this Messaging under Rails control.

I have also

```
#conf/initializers/messaging.rb

Messaging.instance.init # this was cut from post but exists
```

and

```
# config/application.rb
module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
  end
end
```

The code is abstracted but represents a real issue. In the real could occur thread-in-thread and sequential queries, but I use the #with_connection(&block) and completing queries with #to_a or #find within each of the &block. But something is wrong((..

Thanks more for any help!! I am really in stuck with this(

Comment: probably I should `include Messaging` into `Friend`?

Comment: it seems that this is working..

Answer (score 0):

Well, here was my very rough code..

But generally yes - this solution (wrapping queries into ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection{}) works until connections are not intensively used by arbitrary threads. After this, it becomes an mulithreading issue 
[Having a Multithreaded environment in JRuby after ConnectionNotEstablished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498209/having-a-multithreaded-environment-in-jruby-after-connectionnotestablished) , which solving with using Puma gem, or, I guess, other multithreated engines (JRuby, Rainbow!, Thrinidad..) https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyOnRails.